# Getting error while Retrieving data from Google BooksAPI. Can someone tell why it's showing undefined

Tags: node.js, api, express, https

[I am running this one express server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJVYE.png)

[While trying to console log get items data from the API it's showing undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSAP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't parsed the data, therefore it is only a string, with no properties (`.items`). If it's JSON, you'll need to run it through `JSON.parse(...)`, and then try to access it. If that doesn't work, it's probably in a wrong format, I recommend logging just `data`, and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting chunks of data with this handler:

```
let data = '';
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
          });
```

After all chunks are fetched, you simply call:

```
resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```